# Как запретить просматривать файлы на сервере?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

У хостера настроен сервер так, что при попытке посмотреть директорию (по http) без .html файлов выдает - Access denied. Ок, то что надо.

Но в этой директории помимо скриптов лежат еще и конфигурационные текстовые файлы, например, functions.ini, в котором прописаны настройки для скриптов. При прямом вызове браузер спокойно показывает содержимое этих файлов. Как это запретить? При попытке поставить запрет на чтение(200) естественно server error получается, т.к. скриптам то его читать надо.

Я к сожалению не силен в .htaccess, если с помощью него можно такое настроить. Помогите плиз!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Запрет выдачи листинга пустого каталога вам сделан опцией:

```
Options -Indexes
```

А вам нужно ещё дополнительно [запретить просмотр ini-файлов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160376/denying-user-access-to-php-ini-file-with-htaccess):

```
<FilesMatch "functions.ini">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Для апача после 2.4 нужно делать так:

```
<FilesMatch "functions.ini">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Всех ini-файлов и conf-файлов:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ini|conf)$">
</FilesMatch>
```